# Usage of apostrophe within the words to distinguish substantives from verbs

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, word-class, diacritical-marks

Consider the following statements:

- There has been a 10% decrease in the value.
- The value may decrease 10% next month.

In the first sentence, *decrease* is a substantive while it's a verb in the second one. There's no way to distinguish their class other than by the context.

That's what I thought until a friend insisted that, in these cases, susbtantives **must** be written as `'decrease` and verbs `de'crease`, which, in over 8 years of study, I've never seen before. He just won't accept it doesn't exist. Therefore, is it even right? If not (I'm confident it's not!), how can I prove him it's not a thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think your friend is talking about pronunciation rather than writing.

In speech, when "decrease" is a noun, the stress goes on the first syllable: "**de**crease". When "decrease" is a verb, the stress goes on the second syllable: "de**crease**". The writing does not distinguish them.

Many English verbs follow this pattern. There is a tendency in English to put the accent of a noun on the first syllable, and a countertendency to put the accent of a multisyllable verb on the second syllable. This is a *tendency,* not a *rule* (like most things in English).

Here are some more examples:

> The **sus**pect is in custody. The police sus**pect** that he robbed a bank.
>
> If you don't ob**ject**, I'll just throw that **ob**ject into the garbage can.
>
> George re**ject**ed my screenplay. He threw it into pile with all the other **re**jects.
>
> There's a new book coming out under this publisher's **im**print. It's about how geese are im**print**ed with their mother's appearance shortly after birth.

Comment: Ah, I'm pretty sure it's what his book reads. He insisted it was a spelling rule nonetheless.